# jQuery Errors for mobile Nav Bar

Tags: jquery, css, html, nav

I don't know much about jQuery yet, however I am using it to make this nav menu drop down for phone size media queries when the menu button is clicked. I keep getting this error that I cannot figure out.

Uncaught ReferenceError: toggleMenu is not defined meetPractioner.html:53 onclick

the script I am using is this:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js">
    function toggleMenu() {
        $('nav ul li a').slideToggle("fast");
    }
    </script>
```

While the html is:

```
<nav>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="meetPractioner.html">Meet The Practioner</a></li>
          <li><a href="servicesRates.html">Services &#38; Rates</a></li>
          <li><a href="bookAppointment.html">Book Appointment</a></li>
          <li><a href="locationHours.html">Location &#38; Hours</a></li>
          <li><a href="testimonials.html">Testimonials</a></li>
          <li><a href="questions.html">Questions &#38; Answers</a></li>
          <li><a href="benefits.html">Benefits of Massage</a></li>
          <li><a href="bodySense.html">Body Sense Magazine</a></li>
        </ul>
          <a onclick="toggleMenu()" class="menu-bttn">Menu</a>
     </nav>
```

My jsFiddle is http://jsfiddle.net/Floyd/v723oqfc/1/

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your fiddle you did not define toggleMenu.
But try in your document `<head>` the following:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    function toggleMenu() {
        $('nav ul li a').slideToggle("fast");
    }
</script>
```

This should fix your problem.

**Edit**

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/v723oqfc/2/ (note the "No wrap - in `<head>`" at Frameworks & Extensions)

Comment: Thanks! I didn't put that in my fiddle, sorry new to using it. I do however have this in my head. It works in your fiddle, however not on the browser.

Comment: The difference is that you use one `script`-tag and i use two. You need to seperate them. If `script` has a `src`-tag, everything between the opening and closing tag is ignored.